# Is it true that $\displaystyle (Tf)(x)=g(x)+\int_{a}^b k(x, y)f(y)\ dy$ is a contraction in $(C^0([a, b]), d_\infty)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-equations

In $C^0([a, b])=\{f:[a, b]\longrightarrow \mathbb R: f\ \textrm{continuous}\}$ consider the metric $$d_\infty(f, g)=\sup_{x\in [a, b]}|f(x)-g(x)|.$$Let $T:C^0([a, b])\longrightarrow C^0([a, b])$ given by $$(Tf)(x)=g(x)+\int_{a}^b k(x, y)f(y)\ dy,$$ where $k:[a, b]\times [a, b]\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ and $g:[a, b]\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ are continuous functions. Suppose $$\sup_{x\in [a, b]}\int_{a}^b |k(x, y)|\ dy<1.$$ Is it true that $T$ is a contraction?

Recall $T:X\longrightarrow X$ is a contraction in the metric space $(X, d)$ if there is $c<1$ such that $d(Tx, Ty)\leq c d(x, y)$.

Comment: Try to estimate $d(f_1,f_2)$ for $f_1,f_2 \in C^0([a,b])$, using what you have been given. (Hint: the answer should be yes.)

Comment: And use a little  Hölder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$d_\infty(Tf, Th)=
\sup_x \left|
\int_a^b k(x,y) (f(y)-h(y)) dy
\right|
\\
\le
\sup_x \left(
\sup_y |f(y)-h(y)|
\int_a^b |k(x,y)|  dy
\right) 
=
\sup_x \int_a^b |k(x,y)|  dy \times d_\infty(f, h)$$